# Automatically insert blank page if the last page of a chapter is odd

Tags: page-breaking, blank-page, page

I'm writing my master thesis on Latex but, for some reason, I'm unable to automatically start the new chapter on odd pages.

At the moment, as soon as a chapter ends, the new chapter will start on the next page. Because I need to print it, I need that every new chapter starts on an odd page (so I can read it on the right page like in a book)

I'm using `\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,titlepage]{book}` which should manage this kind of thing automatically but it doesn't.

I have also tried to add `\cleardoublepage` and `\clearpage` as below but they do nothing.

```
\input{Include/Chapters/Introduction}
\cleardoublepage
\input{Include/Chapters/Water40}
```

I'm currently using the command `\afterpage{\null\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage}` to create the blank page but this is a manual operation and I want it to be automatic.

My chapters use the style `\thispagestyle{plain}`

Any solution?

Comment: you have specified `oneside` so only the odd side page layout is used. and `\cleardoublepage` is the same as `\clearpage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've just figured out that I was using `oneside` as a parameter on `\documentclass`

Using `\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,titlepage]{book}` fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `book.cls`, then the option `openright` will be useful

```
\documentclass[openright]{book}
```